# Javascript functions within Dojo script run without being called

Tags: javascript, function, dojo, onclick, esri

I am feeling quite stupid about this, but I have a named function within my main Dojo require script that my intention was to run when called by a click event. However, the function runs on loading the page and does not run on the click event.

```
<script>
require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map){
    var map = new Map("map");
    testNode = document.getElementById("testNode");
    testNode.onclick = test();

    function test() {
        alert("test");
    }
}
</script>

<body>
    <div id="testNode">Click Here To Test</div>
    <div id="map></div>
</body>
```

As soon as the page loads the "test" alert pops up and nothing happens on the click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type

```
testNode.onclick = test();
```

You're calling the function `test` and passing the return value of the function to `testNode.onclick`. You should instead assign a reference of the function `test` to `testNode.onclick`:

```
testNode.onclick = test;
```